# Event Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a problem with creating an event. I don't want to use innerHTML so I was trying different methods but none have worked. I'm making calculator, and I was trying to call nums array and itm as number holder but it didn't work. Question is how to make actually working event in there? Sorry if my post lack information, I hope you will be forgiving in this.

**New**, I have been doing a lot of research on my own but I can't find a solution to this. What I'm trying to do is to make operation buttons work like they are supposed to. I can't find a way to store button that I pressed previously and make operation on it. I ask for some hint's to make it work.

```js
var nums = [
  ['7', '8', '9', 'C'],
  ['4', '5', '6', '+'],
  ['1', '2', '3', '-'],
  ['0', '.', '=']
];
var disp = document.getElementById('display');
var calc = document.getElementById('calc'),
  row, itm;

function keyPress(e) {
  console.log("Target:", e.target);
  console.log("Content:", e.target.textContent);
  console.log("Class:", e.target.className);
  disp.textContent = e.target.textContent;
  switch(e.target.textContent) {
    case 'C':
        disp.textContent = '0';
        break;
    case '+':
        //here i have been trying different things to make it work
        //but it seems i get the wrong idea all the time 
        //this n1 is one of the vars i tried to save my numbers in
        disp.textContent = n1 + e.target.textContent;
        break;
    case '-':
        disp.textContent = '0';
        break;
    case '=':
        disp.textContent = '0';
        break;
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  row = document.createElement('div');
  for (let j = 0; j < nums[i].length; ++j) {
    itm = document.createElement('div');
    itm.textContent = nums[i][j];
    if (nums[i][j] === '0')
      itm.setAttribute('class', 'double');
    itm.addEventListener('click', keyPress);
    row.appendChild(itm);
  }
  calc.appendChild(row);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="calc">
    <div>
      <div id="display">0</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Doesn't `itm.addEventListener('click', keyPress);` already work? (Of course it's installing a click handler, not a keypress one)

Comment: Btw, this is a really good use case for a `<table>` element, not nested divs

Comment: So basically i need to make an event that catches the pressed key and will display it on disp right?

Comment: You don't need to "make an event". You just need to move your mouse to the element and click it. That will trigger your `keyPress` function with an event in the `e` parameter.

Comment: It does so i just need to write the e.target.textContent to disp?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Or define the function inside the loop block scope, and refer to `nums[i][j]` directly

Comment: It does not seem to work for me, or I'm just doing something wrong. Sorry if my problems are a bit too obvious for you, but I'm a total newbie.

Comment: Please show us what you did try to write to the display. You can [edit] your question

Comment: Sorry for long time, but my laptop broke and I had to wait for monday to get the parts. I think, that I was thinking wrong way all the time. I'll edit it.

Comment: I did a few changes, would be glad if you take a look on it.

Comment: Where do you declare `n1`? And where do you assign to it?

Comment: as i said it was one of many tries i did before var n1 = disp.textContent, or var n1 = e.target.textContent, it was one of the attempts to store previous numbers.

Comment: You need to declare the `n1` outside of the function `keyPress`, then it should work. Make sure to not overwrite it before trying to read the old value.

Comment: I have been trying different thing for hours now, like adding var n1 = disp.textContent; before function as you suggested. I have tried to make an additional n2 variable to add things up, but what I got was *clicking 6* then after 6 appears I click add button and my display shows 0+ or sometimes ++.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to achieve? I'm guessing you want to do certain things when a key from your array is pressed. You could do something like:

```js
function showKeycode(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode;
    switch(key) {
        case 49:
            console.log('1');
            break;
        case 50:
            console.log('2');
            break;
        case 51:
            console.log('3');
            break;
        case 52:
            console.log('and so on...')
            break;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', showKeycode);
```

To get the keyCode of certain characters use `'6'.charCodeAt(0)`.

Comment: I did not think about using switch here, I can try your idea. I'm just learning JavaScript. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could specify what you want to achieve so I can adjust my answer to your needs. Do you want a fully functional calculator where you can enter numbers via **click** and **keys**?

Comment: only clicks, i just need to make part where it actually displays it, but I want to do everything on events as shown in my script.